# How can I drop all tables with Sequelize.js using postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying:

```
if (process.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  foreignKeyChecks = 0;
  forceSync = true;
} else {
  foreignKeyChecks = 1;
  forceSync = false;
}

global.db.sequelize.query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = " + foreignKeyChecks).then(function() {
  return global.db.sequelize.sync({
    force: forceSync
  });
}).then(function() {
  return global.db.sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}).then(function() {
  var server;
  console.log('Initialzed database on:');
  console.log(config.db);
  return server = app.listen(port, function() {
    return console.log("Server listening at http://" + (server.address().address) + ":" + (server.address().port));
  });
})["catch"](function(err) {
  return console.log('err', err);
});

module.exports = app;
```

But I get: `SequelizeDatabaseError: unrecognized configuration parameter "foreign_key_checks"`

I assume I can't have that keyword in postgres? But is there an equivalent way to drop all tables and recreate?

Comment: There is no such option `foreign_key_checks` in Postgres. Where in the manual did you find that?

Comment: I assumed not. I copied from some post and I assume they were using `MySQL`

Comment: It seems reading the manual is _really_ a lost art.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**This is an updated answer, targeted at the googlers who wound up here like me.**

Sequelize offers a drop function:

```
drop(options) => promise
```

> Drop all tables defined through this sequelize instance. This is done by calling Model.drop on each model. [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#dropoptions-promise)

#### Example

```js
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

var someModel = sequelize.define('somemodel', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
});

sequelize
  .sync() // create the database table for our model(s)
  .then(function(){
    // do some work
  })
  .then(function(){
    return sequelize.drop() // drop all tables in the db
  });
```

Answer (score 13):

For wiping out data and create all again from scratch (like in tests):

```
sequelize.sync({force: true});
```

Comment: You are wrong. It does not delete tables that exist in database but not in sequelize model list

Comment: Sequelize also has `sequelize.truncate` to truncate all tables for those that don't want to actually delete the tables, it could be faster than drop + recreate which `.sync` seems to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66985334/895245

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anything about that JavaScript library, but Postgres provides a single command to drop everything that is owned by a user:

```
drop owned by <our_user_name cascade
```

This will only work if everything is owned by the same user and that user doesn't have some tables (or views, sequences, ...) that you do **not** want to drop.

More details in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html

Comment: Any way to turn off foreign key constraints when dropping tables?

Comment: @Shamoon: you don't need to. The `cascade` keyword will automatically drop all foreign keys.

Comment: I realize that I don't `need` to, but I'm trying to stay within the confines of the ORM

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a solution with sequelize-cli checkout this link [Sequelize CLI](https://github.com/sequelize/cli):

You can just run:

```
sequelize_cli db:drop

sequelize_cli db:create
```

To create or drop your db using the cli tool. This way you will have a empty db.

Answer (score 1):

drop connection with db and:
$ npx sequelize_cli db:drop