# Postgresql truncate table with foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql

Currently I am trying to truncate tables which have foreign key constraint on Postgresql 11.3.

I tried doing this

```
BEGIN; 
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
TRUNCATE tableA;
COMMIT;
```

but received error

```
ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "xxx" references "tableA".
HINT:  Truncate table "xxx" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

Doesn't `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` would turn off the foreign key constraint check? Are there anyway to truncate a table without triggering foreign key constraint check and not involving CASCADE?

Answer (score 48):

**Remove all data from one table**

The simplest form of the  `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement is as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

**Remove all data from table that has foreign key references**

To remove data from the main table and all tables that have foreign key references to the main table, you use `CASCADE` option as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name CASCADE;
```

**Update:**

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: As I understand using CASCADE will affect related tables too which is something I do not want. I want to truncate a table by ignoring the foreign key constraint which may have relationship with other tables.

Comment: If you want to do that, drop the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your final update? What `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` does. Doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: The Update is nonsense. Disabling contraints only disable constraints-checking for the single rows and does not disable the constraint itself which is needed to do a Truncate without cascade. (Truncate by definition, opposed to DELETE FROM, does not do a row by row processing so does only truncate the table - if used with cascade it can work even wih the existing contraint in that it truncates all dependent tables). So the Update would be valid if You would write `DELETE FROM TABLE table_name;` instead of Truncate.

Answer (score 12):

you can do the following steps to avoid the foreign key error during truncate

1. create automated script that DROPS all foreign keys and constraints (do NOT run it yet)
2. create automated script that RE-CREATES all foreign keys and constraints
3. Run drop script
4. run normal TRUNCATE your_table
5. run recreate keys script

with these steps the TRUNCATE command runs fine because there are no foreign keys.

the drop and re-create scripts are taken from https://blog.hagander.net/automatically-dropping-and-creating-constraints-131/

DROP SCRIPT:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "'||nspname||'"."'||relname||'" DROP CONSTRAINT "'||conname||'";'
 FROM pg_constraint 
 INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid 
 INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN contype='f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,contype,nspname,relname,conname
```

RECREATE SCRIPT:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "'||nspname||'"."'||relname||'" ADD CONSTRAINT "'||conname||'" '||
   pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid)||';'
 FROM pg_constraint
 INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid
 INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN contype='f' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC,contype DESC,nspname DESC,relname DESC,conname DESC;
```

Comment: This worked very nicely, although I did have to steps before and after step 4. One step before it to copy data from the target table for truncate (that I wanted to save) into a temporary table. Afterwards I copied the saved data back into the target table, then I also ran a script to update the foreign key table so only the foreign keys that remained in the target table were still set in the related table. Drop and recreate scripts very handy thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you can truncate all related tables using the command

TRUNCATE TABLE table_1 , table_2 ,table_3 <etc...> ;

Comment: this didn't work for me for some reason

Answer (score 3):

this works for me so nice

```
TRUNCATE table_name RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
```

I used `RESTART IDENTITY` which resets the sequences associated with the table columns

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because my **Sqitch** data revert script used TRUNCATE. A workaround that may not be ideal for everyone (but worked for me):

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE id IN (
  '5b50e44a-e8dd-4950-8708-588d6620d578',
  'd1857bfa-43bc-4284-8a49-c6ceba80a66f',
  '3ddff193-eb9f-495b-b63d-87b4e0637caa'
  --etc
);
```